Cubic forms over abelian groups
Let $G$ and $A$ be abelian groups, denoted additively. A symmetric bilinear form is a map $b: G\times G\rightarrow A$ such that $b(g,h+h')=b(g,h)+b(g,h')$, $b(g,0)=0$, $b(g,h)=b(h,g)$. A quadratic refinement of $b$ is a map $q: G\rightarrow A$ such that
$$q(a+b)-q(a)-q(b)=b(a,b)\;.$$
Quadratic refinements are something I come across in theoretical physics all the time. I'm wondering whether there exists a generalization to a "cubic refinement" $c:G\rightarrow A$ of a symmetric trilinear form $t:G\times G\times G\rightarrow A$ (with $t(g,h,i+i')=t(g,h,i)+t(g,h,i')$, $t(g,h,0)=0$, $t(g,h,i)=t(h,g,i)=t(g,i,h)$)?
For example, the function $c:\mathbb Z_2\rightarrow \mathbb Z/\mathbb R$ defined by $c(0)=0$ and $c(1)=\frac18$ is "cubic" since $c(u\cdot x)=u^3\cdot c(x)$, and it would be nice to see this as some sort of "cubic refinement" of the trilinear form $t:\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\rightarrow \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ defined by $t(a,b,c)=\frac12 a\cdot b\cdot c$.

I am not sure if a terminology for cubic refinements exist in the existing literature or if this even helps (I might be a bit away from your field of study); but the expression for the quadratic refinement (which I admit I am seeing for the first time) reminds me of this:
Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that the $q(a,b)$ is inspired by the identity $$(a+b)^2 - a^2 -b^2 = 2 ab$$ where the right hand side is a bilear form. In this case, I think the natural thing to consider would be to have a similar expression for the trilinear form $t(a,b,c) = k \cdot a b c$, where $k$ is a constant. For this we can see that
$$(a+b+c)^3 - (a+b)^3-(b+c)^3 - (c+a)^3 +a^3+b^3+c^3 = 6 abc$$ will indeed give us such an expression.
So, how about defining a cubic refinement of a trilinear form $t(a,b,c)$ as
a function $q$ satisfying $$q(a+b+c) -q(a+b) -q(b+c) -q(a+c) +q(a) +q(b) +q(c) = t(a,b,c)$$ Will that give you something that has all the properties that you are looking for?

Also, just to add in case that helps, it might be possible that this can be generalised to the $n$-linear form given by $f(x_1,\cdots, x_n) = n! \cdot x_1\cdots x_n$, by proving the identity that $$\sum_{\phi \neq A\subset \{1,\cdots,n\}; }(-1)^{n-|A|} (\sum_{i\in A} x_i)^n = n!\cdot x_1\cdots x_n$$

Edit: Sign error. Edited to correct that now.

Thanks so much! I don't know yet all properties that I want, but this makes a lot of sense and successfully describes all 3 main examples I wanted to be covered:

$G=\mathbb Z_2$, $A=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, $c(a)=\frac18 a$, $t(a,b,c)=\frac12 abc$

$G=\mathbb Z_2^3$, $A=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, $c((a_0,a_1,a_2))=\frac12 a_0 a_1 a_2$, $t((a_0,a_1,a_2),(b_0,b_1,b_2),(c_0,c_1,c_2)=\frac12(a_0b_1c_2+a_0c_1b_2+b_0a_1c_2+b_0c_1a_2+c_0a_1b_2+c_0b_1a_2)$

$G=\mathbb Z_2^2$, $A=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, $c((a_0,a_1))=\frac14 a_0 a_1$, $t((a_0,a_1),(b_0,b_1),(c_0,c_1))=\frac12(a_0b_1c_1+a_1b_0c_1+a_1b_1c_0+a_1b_0c_0+a_0b_1c_0+a_0b_0c_1)$

Does anybody know if there is a name for functions $c$ related to cubic forms $t$ in the suggested way?

@AndiBauer  You're welcome! Glad it was helpful! Regarding the name, I hope someone else could help you with that. :)
